# Are semi-direct products and fiber products similar constructions in different categories?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, category-theory

We have direct product of groups which is basically like attaching two groups together by forming the Cartesian product and defining component-wise multiplication. Similarly, we have product of manifolds which seems to be the same idea. We attach two given manifolds by forming the Cartesian product and then we parameterize it by attaching their coordinates.

Then we have a construction called semi-direct product that generalizes the direct product by requiring only one block to be normal. We know that the normal block can be thought of as the kernel of a map. 
We know that fiber bundles are a generalization of product manifolds that may be twisted globally, even though they look like product manifolds locally.
The thing is that the fibers are projected into one point. So, in some sense it's like they can be somehow thought of as the kernel of some projection.

Is there a relation between these two concepts? Like fiber product is a similar notion like semi-direct product of groups but in the category of manifolds?

Comment: The fiber product of spaces/manifolds is a pushout. The pushout in the category of groups is the amalgamated free product. I'm not sure I would believe that these are at all similar constructions, but I'm no category theorist.

Comment: The fibre product is a _pullback_. The semidirect product of groups is neither a limit nor a colimit – not in the category of groups anyway. However, it can be described as a pseudocolimit in the category of groupoids...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, fiber products are a [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)), or a kind of limit. The semidirect product is actually not a product at all: it is a [homotopy quotient](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+quotient), or a kind of [homotopy colimit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_colimit).

In particular it is possible to describe semidirect products in greater generality than just involving groups, and in this greater generality one of the objects remains a group but the others don't: for example, if a group $G$ acts on a ring $R$ then there is a corresponding semidirect or "crossed" product ring $R \rtimes G$, which is the homotopy quotient of $R$ by this action.

There is a relationship between semidirect products and fiber *bundles* (as opposed to fiber products), which is that any semidirect product $N \rtimes H$ gives rise to a fiber bundle

$$BN \to B(N \rtimes H) \to BH$$

of [classifying spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space). There is also a more complicated relationship in the other direction: in fact every fiber bundle can be described using a homotopy colimit construction.

Comment: Do you happen to know of a reference that explains how fibre bundles can be described by homotopy colimits? I am just reading about homotopy limits now and I'm curious about how to do this.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ: the Grothendieck construction for spaces establishes an equivalence between fiber bundles over a space $X$ and functors from $X$ into spaces (by which I mean $\infty$-groupoids). To get from a functor to the total space of the fiber bundle you take its homotopy colimit.